# What is the coinbase?

Tags: protocol, mining-reward, coinbase-transaction

I searched the bitcoin wiki and found references to coinbase, but no clear cut explanation of what exactly it is.  I know that miners can tag their coinbases (that is how some sites tell who mined a block).

Comment: Not to be confused with the Bitcoin startup Coinbase, which is a hosted (shared) EWallet + exchange.

Comment: For questions about the company see the tag [tag:coinbase.com].

Answer (score 32):

The term "coinbase" is used to mean many different things. But the two you're probably asking about are:

1. The "coinbase transaction" is the transaction inside a block that pays the miner his block reward.
2. Inside the coinbase transaction is a field that is called the "coinbase". It's the [generation transaction's](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transactions#Generation) equivalent of a scriptsig. Since it doesn't claim any existing outputs, it needs no normal scriptsig. It's basically just a random value that the miner can use as an additional nonce. [BIP 34](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0034) changes this a bit.

Comment: There's also now a Bitcoin exchange/hosted wallet web site called http://www.coinbase.com.

Answer (score 11):

David has already given a good explanation of the term coinbase, but I'd like to give further details on the **coinbase transaction**.

The *coinbase transaction* is a special type of transaction.

- Every block must have a coinbase transaction, [other transactions are optional](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2021/5406).
- The coinbase transaction must be the first transaction of the block (it follows that there can only be one per block).
- The coinbase's output is used to send the block reward, i.e. block subsidy plus transaction fees, to the miner's address.
- The coinbase transaction can have an arbitrary input of 100 byte size. E.g. this was where the genesis block famously contained "The Times 03/Jan/2009 Chancellor on brink of second bailout for banks". This is also the field that may be used for the [`extranonce`](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5048/5406).