# Must a Block contain a coinbase transaction?

Tags: block, mining-reward, coinbase-transaction

Must a block contain a coinbase transaction? If so, how is this enforced?

Comment: related: [What is the coinbase?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4571/5406)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Every block must include one or more transactions. The first one of these transactions must be a coinbase transaction which should collect and spend the block reward and any transaction fees paid by transactions included in this block.

Bitcoin Foundation Developer Guide— https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#transaction-data

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it must.

Block without coinbase transaction will be rejected by network.

From the [Protocol](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_rules#.22block.22_messages), rule #6:

> First transaction must be coinbase (i.e. only 1 input, with hash=0, n=-1), the rest must not be

Comment: The coinbase transaction is important as the mark of bitcoin generation. But what would it be for when the last bitcoin were mined?