# Bitcoin mining sharing

Tags: mining-theory, mining-reward, solo-mining

How to share new block and get reward without pools?
For example i find next block what do with it?
Where i can send solutions to get reward?
I can find new block in solo mining but don't know where it share.

Comment: Mining solo doesn't share rewards with others. Hence the name, 'solo mining.'

Comment: But then What is the command or the option in the wallet to send the new minned Block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need when trying to mine on your own for bitcoin is to set up a bitcoin node for yourself. The main way to do this is to run Bitcoin-QT (or Bitcoin Core) downloaded from https://bitcoin.org/en/download. 
Once you have a full node set up, you can then point a bitcoin miner/bitcoin miner(s) towards it. 
After you have done this, you merely have to wait as now you're "solo mining" and will get the full 12.5 block reward to yourself if you mine a block (everything should be automatically sorted after this point). As Bitcoin is decentralised, other nodes close to you have the statistics of other bitcoin nodes and know when there's another blockadded to those nodes which they need to download. Once this has happened, the network is able to confirm that you mined the block and can send the 12.5btc to you. (NOTE: if you do not have enough power, it is unlikely you will ever recieve a profit on mining in this way).

Comment: -1 This answer appears to be pretty confusing to me: "You can solo mine with multiple people/miners."  is oxymoronic, since "solo mining" means that you mine by yourself. In the second part, you constrain by saying "without a pool" and then continue by giving instructions on how to create a pool. This answer should be reworked or removed.

Comment: Thanks for stating your improvements. I have rewritten my post.

Comment: Much better! Minor nit: The coinbase transaction (the first transaction in the block) is the one that creates the money and sends it to you. Therefore, the moment that you create a valid block, you're paying yourself (if it becomes part of the longest chain). I also think that you need additional software to connect your node and the mining hardware, but I actually don't know for sure.

Comment: I didn't know about the coinbase transaction. And actually no, I don't think you need any additional software once you have bitcoin core set up as a node as the additional software that's needed comes with things like (bfgminer, cgminer - which are to be installed on the miner). cgminer is software preinstalled onto bitmain antminers (developed by --ck on bitcointalk if I remeber correctly).

Comment: Coinbase: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4571/5406

Answer (score 0):

You share the block by broadcasting it on the Bitcoin peer-to-peer network.  This will ensure that other miners know about it and can mine their next blocks on top of it.

When you created the block, you included a coinbase transaction which pays the reward to an address belonging to you.  This can be spent after an additional 100 blocks have been mined.

Normally your mining software takes care of all this for you.