# Why do some addresses seem to send bitcoin to themselves?

Tags: change, address-reuse

When looking at [block 630873](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000009eefb7971196febbea455b2bbc18ea65b57c64054fa03), I noticed that some addresses seem to send BTC to themselves:

[image]

Am I misunderstanding the situation, or does `1A7tWftaGHohhGcJMVkkm4zAYnF53KjRnU` send large sums of BTC to itself? If that is the case, why is it beneficial?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/95773/5406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of transaction is very popular amongst exchanges with hotwallet scheme. They use hotwallet (in this case the 1A7... address looks like it) to send withdrawals to clients, the change is going back to the hotwallet. 
Most bitcoin wallets don't allow for this behavior, creating a fresh change address every transaction.